# C# - using method extensions with Expression.Property()

Tags: c#, expression

i am trying to build an expression using method extensions. Unfortunately this seems not to work straight forward. The code sample below gives a method not found exception.

Anyone an idea how I can use the method extension in the Extension.Property method?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new TestProperty();
        var propertyExpr2 = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(obj), "Sample");
        propertyExpr2 = Expression.Property(propertyExpr2, "GetValueOrDefault");

        Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(propertyExpr2).Compile()());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string GetValueOrDefault(this string s)
    {
        return s ?? "Testing";
    }
}

public class TestProperty
{
    public string Sample { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: At a guess your problem is that `GetValueOrDefault` isn't a property so `Expression.Property` is clearly not going to work. From a 2 second google I would guess you want `Expression.Call` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323927(v=vs.110).aspx) that says is used to represent a method call.

Comment: I'll add that you could have let the compiler generate the Expression and then analyzed it in the debugger: `Expression<Func<string>> exp = () => obj.Sample.GetValueOrDefault();`

Comment: Thank you guys, `Expression.Call` is obviously the right solution! Seems like the method extension confused me..

`var ex1 = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(obj), "Sample");
 var ex2 = Expression.Call(typeof(StringExtension).GetMethod("GetValueOrDefault"), ex1, Expression.Constant("Testing"));
            
Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(ex2).Compile()());`